# Best way to use SFINAE to disable an otherwise-non-templated member function of a class template?

Tags: c++, c++-templates

There are many similar-looking questions, but I can't find quite this one: Given

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct S {
    int f(int x) const { return x; }
};
```

I want to be able to SFINAE-away `f` depending on some metafunction of `T`. The obvious thing doesn't work:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct MyProperty { static constexpr auto value = std::is_same_v<T, float>; };

template <typename T>
struct S {
    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<MyProperty<T>::value>>
    int f(int x) const { return x; }
};

int main() {
    S<int> s;
}
```

The closest I can come is a dummy `typename U = T`:

```
    template <typename U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<MyProperty<U>::value>>
    int f(int x) const { 
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, U>, "Don't provide U.");
        return x;
    }
```

which works https://godbolt.org/z/8qGs6P8Wd but feels round-about. Is there a better way?

Comment: It doesn't scale well but you could specialize the class itself.  It's not DRY and IMHO a worse solution then what you already have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use C++20 or later, add a constraint:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct S {
    int f(int x) const requires MyProperty<T>::value { 
        return x;
    }
};
```

---

In C++17, you could do it like you do it now or move the `enable_if` to be used for the function's return type. If you put the condition `std::is_same_v<U, T>` in the `enable_if` too instead of in a `static_assert`, it'll be more SFINAE friendly in case you want to enable other `f`s.

```cpp
template<class T>
struct S {
    template<class U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T> && MyProperty<U>::value, int> 
    f(int x) const { 
        return x;
    }
};
```

---

Another option that can be useful if you have many functions in your class that you'd like to enable only if `MyProperty::value` is `true` is to put all those functions in a base class and inherit from that class conditionally using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```cpp
struct empty {};

template<class T>
struct float_funcs {
    T& Self() { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
    const T& Self() const { return *static_cast<const T*>(this); }

    // put all functions depending on the MyProperty trait being true here:
    int f(int x) const {
        return x + Self().foo; // `foo` is accessible since we're a friend
    }
};

template<class T> // added helper variable
inline constexpr bool MyProperty_v = MyProperty<T>::value;

// inherit from float_funcs<S<T>> if the condition is `true` or `empty` otherwise
template<class T>
struct S : std::conditional_t<MyProperty_v<T>, float_funcs<S<T>>, empty> {
private:
    friend std::conditional_t<MyProperty_v<T>, float_funcs<S<T>>, empty>;
    int foo = 1;
};
```

With this you don't need SFINAE away `f` and you'll get a clear compilation error if you try to use `f` when `MyProperty<T>` is not fulfilled. `f` doesn't even exist in any form in that case.

Comment: Personally I prefer to tuck `std::enable_if_t` in the `template <...>` so the return type isn't buried in it. I chose the `static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, U>, "Don't provide U.");` approach because it should be a hard error for someone to call `s.foo<float>(0);`.

Comment: @Ben Sure, it's a matter of taste where you put the `enable_if`. I personally prefer to not add the extra dummy template parameter to the function if possible. The `static_assert` is certainly the best option if you don't need to SFINAE-enable other `f`s. I just put it in as an option. Cleanest is the C++20 version for sure. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++20, you can constrain the function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct S {
    int f(int x) const requires(MyProperty<T>::value) { return x; }
};
```

Otherwise you can use inheritance:

```cpp
template <typename Self, typename T, typename = void>
struct MyPropertyS {};

template <typename Self, typename T>
struct MyPropertyS<Self, T, std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<MyProperty<T>::value>>> {
    // Access rest of class via `static_cast<Self&>(*this)`
    int f(int x) const { return x; }
};

template<typename T>
struct S : MyPropertyS<S<T>, T> {
    // Inherit f if it exists
};
```

(Or specialize the whole struct `S` itself instead of inheriting a part that is conditionally changed)

These are the only ways you can truly conditionally have a non-template member function.

Otherwise, your template method is good. You might also want to consider something like this:

```cpp
struct disabled {
    disabled() = delete;
    ~disabled() = delete;
};

template <typename T>
struct S {
    int f(std::conditional_t<MyProperty<T>::value, int, disabled> x) const { return x; }
};
```

which won't get rid of `f`, but you won't be able to call it and `s.f(0)` will be a SFINAE friendly fail (and it's easy to reuse for multiple functions with a type alias)